# Data type torch matrix multiplication bug complex and real layer

Tags: python, debugging, pytorch

I am learning torch, and I am creating a layer which includes the multiplication of a real and a complex matrix. I was wondering why I cannot multiply a complex matrix and a real matrix together

```
torch.randn(2,2, dtype=torch.complex64) @ torch.randn(2,2)

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[85], line 1
----> 1 torch.randn(2,2, dtype=torch.complex64) @ torch.randn(2,2)

RuntimeError: expected m1 and m2 to have the same dtype, but got: struct c10::complex<float> != float
```

I am aware that I could use

```
.to(torch.complex64)
```

but this gives me issues in my layer class. Is there another solution?

Comment: The answer depends on what you are trying to achieve. In principle `torch.randn(2,2, dtype=torch.complex64) @ torch.randn(2,2).to(torch.complex64)` is the right approach. Why does this lead to further issues?